# How to INSERT a new row if value does not already exist in a column in table

Tags: postgresql

Title says it all. I know there are a million non-nodejs solutions to this but I need one that works with the node-postgres module.

(NOTE: I am using Heroku as a host so I get free Postgresql access, meaning I can't make/add functions as it's the free version.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As of PostgreSQL 9.5](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.5#INSERT_..._ON_CONFLICT_DO_NOTHING.2FUPDATE_.28.22UPSERT.22.29) (which Heroku has had since the beginning of 2016), you can have the insert ignored if there is a duplicate entry (determined by existing uniqueness constraints).

The following examples are taken from the PostgreSQL wiki:

`INSERT INTO countries (country) VALUES ('France'),('Japan') ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;`

The above insert query will ignore *any* conflicts. However, this may not be desirable, so what you can do instead is explicitly state which constraint(s) should be considered when deciding to ignore the insert:

`INSERT INTO countries (country) VALUES ('France'),('Japan') ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT countries_pkey DO NOTHING;`

or

`INSERT INTO countries (country) VALUES ('France'),('Japan') ON CONFLICT (country) DO NOTHING;`

That way other constraints are not swallowed and will still result in an error.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much :)